# DatabaseError "no such column"

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

for some reason I'm getting a `DatabaseError "no such column: myapp_customer.redirect_link_id"`.  Someone who has the same exact code as me on another computer doesn't have this issue.  We use Django-South for migration and  according to it i'm completely up to date with the model:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
Nothing seems to have changed.

$ python manage.py migrate myapp
Running migrations for myapp:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for myapp.
No fixtures found.
```

Here's a full stack trace:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/me/sources/django_myapp/../django_myapp/myapp/views.py" in main_page
  66.         customer = Customer.objects.select_related().get(user = request.user)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  344.         num = len(clone)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  82.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  273.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  680.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  234.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /
Exception Value: no such column: myapp_customer.redirect_link_id
```

I ran `manage.py sqlall myapp` and according to it, the redirect_link_id is present in the db:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_customer" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "client_key" varchar(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "api_key" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "redirect_link_id" integer REFERENCES "myapp_full_link" ("id"),
    "message_title" varchar(200),
    "message_body" text,
    "customer_group_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "myapp_customer_group" ("id")
)
;
```

Comment: The 'myapp_full_link' table is existing and has integrity?

Comment: sqlall does not show you the current state of your database. It shows the SQL required to set up your database from scratch. Use the dbshell command instead, then '.schema' (for SQLite)

Comment: So according to sqllite, the myapp_customer table actually doesn't have the `redirect_link_id` column.  `myapp_full_link` does indeed exist  Question: why didn't the South migration create the column based on my model?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you also have the most recent migration files from myapp/migrations directory?

Comment: I'm quite sure.  I double checked the working machine and there are no untracked migrations there.

Comment: ``./manage.py migrate --list`` might also give some pointers on the status of migrations. Other than that I'd suggest checking the actual current schema on database level, and comparing its current state with the migration records from south_migrationhistory table to see where it went wrong.

Comment: the working and non-working machines have the same output from that command.  Also, see above, I ran manage.py sqlall and it seems to imply that I have the column in the actual db

Comment: I'm starting to be out of suggestions. Have you ran the ``migrate`` command before on your machine or is this the first time you are applying the migrations? I don't see why the migrations wouldn't have been applied other than, like, the migrations were previously applied on your machine with ``--fake`` flag or something.